# TFS 2012 deploying mutliple profiles after build

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am currently using a build definition for continuous integration in TFS 2012.

I am using the following build arguments

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DEV_SERVER;Password=secret
```

and everything works well.

Now I need to **publish the build to more than one site**, and I have created the publishing profiles in visual studio. But how to tell `MSBuild` to use more than one profile?

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DEV_SERVER1;Password=secret /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DEV_SERVER2;Password=secret /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=DEV_SERVER3;Password=secret
```

does not work. Only one site is published. (I'm not sure the first or last)

Does anyone know how to specify?

I know that I can duplicate the build definition on TFS using another profile in this new build definition, but in this case the application will be built TWO times and the releases on the servers have different build numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify publish xml in the MSBuild arguments

/t:Build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=DEV.publish.xml

also this option only works for TFS2012 and VS2012

Comment: I'm not sure how this could solve my issue.

Where to place this DEV.publish.xml and what to place inside to refer to the existing publishing profiles in the Properties\Publishing Profiles Folder of VS so that all of them are deployed after a successfull build? May you give me some hints?

Comment: are you using VS2012 along with TFS2012 ? New Visual Studio 2012 creates XML publish profiles. This will only help if you are using VS2012 also

Comment: Yes, I am using VS 2012 (2013) along with TFS 2012 (2013). And yes I am aware of the xml files for the publishing profiles. My problem is that I can only set ONE of them via commandline for deployment. I want to deploy ALL those profiles after a successfull build.

Comment: all that publish does is drops the published files to there. I cant think of a scenario where you need multiple drop locations.

Comment: This is not true. Publishing profiles hold database and other settings that are different on the sites. So the sites have the same binaries and views, but the web.config, global.asax and other configurations may be different.